# Ошибка Django:ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, django

[image][image]Столкнулся с ошибкой при изучении Django по книжке:

[image]

[image]

```
#Это код.
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не скриншотами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`namespace` это именованный аргумент функции `include`, [примеры](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#id5).

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

В модуле `urls.py` приложения `learning_logs` добавьте `app_name = 'learning_logs'` над переменной `urlpatterns`

update:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'learning_log/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95999/discussion-on-answer-by-avtomato--djangovalueerror-dictionary-update-seq).